# Can I request a user's location with an adaptive card?

Tags: adaptive-cards

Is there any way to obtain/request a user's location (i.e. lat/long) using adaptive cards (preferably via sms channel)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adaptive Cards are declarative JSON payloads, so the information shown in them is not dynamic. There is nothing stopping you from using a library or some service that provides this information, before you display or build the Adaptive Card